# Understanding memory leaks in Java . What are the classes that persist through out the life of a Java application? 

Tags: java, memory-leaks

From this [IBM article on handling memory leaks in Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/) :

> The garbage collector starts at the root nodes, classes that persist
>   throughout the life of a Java application, and sweeps through all of
>   the nodes that are referenced. As it traverses the nodes, it keeps
>   track of which objects are actively being referenced. Any classes that
>   are no longer being referenced are then eligible to be garbage
>   collected. The memory resources used by these objects can be returned
>   to the Java virtual machine (JVM) when the objects are deleted.

What are the classes that persist through out the life of a Java application ?

Comment: Anything the EDT holds onto, anything managed by a framework etc, instances held by the starting point of your app.

Comment: Because java classes inherited from the only one class Object so this class was persist through java app

Comment: @Geek EDT is the event dispatch thread, the background stuff that handles Swing/AWT. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: Isn't it application dependent? How can you generalize this? You application may have class X and my application have class Y, so I feel answer for this question would be application dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is also called Garbage Collection Roots. From [Yourkit's documentation of GC roots](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/gc_roots.jsp):

> There are several kinds of GC roots. One object can belong to more than one kind of root. The root kinds are:

> Class - class loaded by system class loader. Such classes can never be unloaded. They    can hold objects via static fields. Please note that classes loaded by custom class loaders are not roots, unless corresponding instances of java.lang.Class happen to be roots of other kind(s).

> Thread - live thread

> Stack Local - local variable or parameter of Java method

> JNI Local - local variable or parameter of JNI method

> JNI Global - global JNI reference

> Monitor Used - objects used as a monitor for synchronization

> Held by JVM - objects held from garbage collection by JVM for its purposes. Actually the list of such objects depends on JVM implementation. Possible known cases are: the system class loader, a few important exception classes which the JVM knows about, a few pre-allocated objects for exception handling, and custom class loaders when they are in the process of loading classes. Unfortunately, JVM provides absolutely no additional detail for such objects. Thus it is up to the analyst to decide to which case a certain "Held by JVM" belongs.

You can also read it from [The Truth About Garbage Collection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html) (dated).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "universal" answer to your question. Each program will only retain the "active" classes (assuming the program runs long enough under enough memory pressure to force inactive classes out)

When your java program starts up, java will load your class containing the public static void main(String []) method... Any classes and objects it instantiated or references will be loaded on demand as you follow the chain of execution.

If the main class forks any threads that will create parallel live paths of execution.

Each path of execution has an associated call stack.

Every class and object referenced by every call stack represents the starting point for the initial live set in java. Follow every reference from that live set and you will have found all the live objects. The JVM spec guarantees that all the live objects and classes will be retained. (that does not mean the others will not be retained by a lazy JVM, but they are not reachable so who cares)