# Must we set null for each element of a list in Java when we want to delete the list

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm trying to develop some tree-like data structure with Java.

```
class MyTree {
    private Node root;
}

class Node {
    private HashMap<Character, Node> children;
    private String content;
    // some other data members
}
```

As you see, each `Node` contains another `Node`, which is its children so that I can build a list like this: `MyTree.root -> child1 -> child2 -> child3`.

Now, if I want to delete/free this tree, can I simply do `root = null;` or must I loop to set each element to null? I don't know how gc exactly works in this case...

Comment: Garbage collection will free all objects which are not reachable from a "gc root". In this case you don't need to set the elements to null -- once root is null all the children are unreachable (assuming there are no other references to them)

Comment: @tgdavies There are no other references to them but they reference themselves as `child1 -> child2 -> ...`. Anyway, so I need only do `root = null;`. Thanks dude.

Comment: here's some more information on gc roots: https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/gc_roots.jsp

Comment: Yes, I should have said "...no other references to them starting from a GC root"

Comment: @tgdavies Perhaps you can make an Answer of that useful info?

Comment: @BasilBourque it actually already mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242904/understanding-memory-leaks-in-java-what-are-the-classes-that-persist-through-o/12242950#12242950 (although the link had rotted, which I've just fixed)